# Issues using libpcap in C in OS X

Tags: c, macos, libpcap

I am trying to compile https://github.com/samueldotj/dhcp-client on Mac OSX. The code compile fine on my linux.

The part of the code (dhcp-client.c) that create issue is replicated below

```
/*
 * Get MAC address of given link(dev_name)
 */
static int
get_mac_address(char *dev_name, u_int8_t *mac)
{
#ifdef __linux__
    struct ifreq s;
    int fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    int result;

    strcpy(s.ifr_name, dev_name);
    result = ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &s);
    close(fd);
    if (result != 0)
        return -1;

    memcpy((void *)mac, s.ifr_addr.sa_data, 6);
    return 0;
#else
    struct ifaddrs *ifap, *p;

    if (getifaddrs(&ifap) != 0)
        return -1;

    for (p = ifap; p; p = p->ifa_next)
    {
        /* Check the device name */
        if ((strcmp(p->ifa_name, dev_name) == 0) &&
            (p->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK))
        {
            struct sockaddr_dl* sdp;

            sdp = (struct sockaddr_dl*) p->ifa_addr;
            memcpy((void *)mac, sdp->sdl_data + sdp->sdl_nlen, 6);
            break;
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(ifap);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
LDLIBS = -lpcap

dhcp-client: dhcp-client.c
```

Relevant Error output

```
cc     dhcp-client.c  -lpcap -o dhcp-client
dhcp-client.c:153:36: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct sockaddr_dl'
            memcpy((void *)mac, sdp->sdl_data + sdp->sdl_nlen, 6);
```

Can someone help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
#ifndef __linux__
#include <net/if_dl.h>
#endif
```

to the top of the file.